# To know the time POST data is stored in one session

Tags: php, post

**How long is the POST data from forms stored in a session such that you can access it by the following command in PHP?**

```
$_POST['email']
```

I have 777 forms and each give me data in the POST -form.
Each name of the input is unique.

I would like to know where is limit about the POST -data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post data is only available for one specific call to the PHP page. It is sent with the HTTP request and available that time only. The next time the user submits another form, only the information from that form is available in $_POST. If you want to save the data in the session, you must do so by hand.